# How can I optimize this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression, and I would like to ask whether it is possible to simplify it?

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}) (([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\:[0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]?) поступление на сумму (\d+) WM([A-Z]) от корреспондента (\d+)/', $message->getMessageBody(), $info);
```

Comment: Can you explain logically what you are trying to test for?

Comment: well, for one, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` - not sure that's what you mean by simplify though

Comment: @Phillip I want to disassemble the a message from the system Webmoney. Example message: 21.07.2013 2:41:51 поступление на сумму 1 WMR от корреспондента 233581779181

Comment: You don't have to escape the colons.

Comment: @PavelAnossov, I did not understand you

Comment: `[0-5][0-9]?` this part actually looks wrong to me. It would seem like if you would want one of those two to be optional, it would be the first one, like `[0-5]?[0-9]` to allow for 0-9 or 00-59

Comment: @MaximSeshuk: `\:` is unnecessary, `:` will work.

Comment: I'd just use `/([\d.]+ [\d:]+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/` to extract the three data and use a proper datetime parser (`strptime` at least) to validate the datetime.

Comment: You go through all this trouble to validate the time and still you accept arbitrary months and days. If you add date and month validation, you have to worry about how many days each month has. Then there are leap years. Then leap seconds. It's just not worth it to try to validate a datetime with a regex.

Comment: @PavelAnossov If not difficult to change how you think it is right all the regular expression. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Comment: @AndyLester Do not provide your version of my modifications?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best you can do:

```
preg_match_all('/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4}) (([01]?\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}) поступление на сумму (\d+) WM([A-Z]) от корреспондента (\d+)/', $message, $info);
```

Unless you don't need those exact words in there. Then you could:

```
preg_match_all('/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4}) (([01]?\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})\D+(\d+) WM([A-Z])\D+(\d+)/', $message, $info);
```

Comment: Would \d\d be any faster or slower than \d{2}? It does save one character. Would allowing any digits, and then confirming that they form legitimate times and dates, be better than trying to sort it all out in the regexp?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using free-spacing mode and some comments (which will help your and everyone else's understanding - which makes simplifying easier). Note that you'll have to put literal spaces in parentheses now, though:

```
/
(             # group 1
  [0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}
              # match a date
)
[ ]
(             # group 2
  (           # group 3
    [01]?[0-9]# match an hour from 0 to 19
  |           # or
    2[0-3]    # match an hour from 20 to 23
  )
  \:       
  [0-5][0-9]  # minutes
  \:
  [0-5][0-9]? # seconds
)
[ ]поступление[ ]на[ ]сумму[ ]
              # literal text
(\d+)         # a number into group 4
[ ]WM         # literal text
([A-Z])       # a letter into group 5
[ ]от[ ]корреспондента[ ]
              # literal text
(\d+)         # a number into group 6
/x
```

Now we can't simplify the part at the end - unless you don't want to capture the parenthesised things, in which case you can simply omit most of the parentheses.

You can slightly shorten the expression, by using `\d` as a substitute for `\d`, in which case `\d\d` is even shorter than `\d{2}`.

Next, there is no need to escape colons.

And finally, there seems to be something odd with your seconds. If you want to allow single-digit seconds, make the `0-5` optional, and not the the `\d` after it:

```
/
(             # group 1
  \d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}
              # match a date
)
[ ]
(             # group 2
  (           # group 3
    [01]?\d   # match an hour from 0 to 19
  |           # or
    2[0-3]    # match an hour from 20 to 23
  )
  :       
  [0-5]\d     # minutes
  :
  [0-5]?\d    # seconds
)
[ ]поступление[ ]на[ ]сумму[ ]
              # literal text
(\d+)         # a number into group 4
[ ]WM         # literal text
([A-Z])       # a letter into group 5
[ ]от[ ]корреспондента[ ]
              # literal text
(\d+)         # a number into group 6
/x
```

I don't think it will get much simpler than that.